# populating a line with points and then looking for intersection with contours

Tags: c++, opencv, line, intersection, points

I have two points which I would like to connect with a line in (OpenCv2.4 Visual c++ 2010).

I am looking for the intersection between points on his line and contours which I have found using findContours.

My question is how would I populate a structure with points from this line in order to check for any intersections with the contour ????

If yo could just provide a way to come up with points on the line it would be good.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, can you not  just draw the contour in img0, draw the line in img1 (both with lineType=8) and then compute img2 = img0  && img1 ?

Comment: you would still be left with just two points without any populating of the vector ......the algorithm suggested looks like the way to go

Comment: Sorry, I understood you actually wanted these two points

Answer (score 0):

A correct way to do it would be to compute the [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm):

> The Bresenham line algorithm is an algorithm which determines which
>   points in an n-dimensional raster should be plotted in order to form a
>   close approximation to a straight line between two given points.

OpenCV drawLine function probably uses this algorithm.
Another way to do it, if speed is not an issue: draw the line in a mask image, then loop over the pixels in this mask (or at least a ROI around your line) and collect the coordinates of the points:

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(originalImage.size(), CV_8U);
cv::Point p1, p2;
std::vector<cv::Point> points;
cv::line(mask, p1, p2, CV_RGB(255,255,255), CV_AA);
for (int row = min(p1.y, p2.y); row < max(p1.y, p2.y); ++row) 
  for (int col = min(p1.x, p2.x); col < max(p1.x, p2.x); ++col)
    if(mask.at<unsigned char>(row, col) != 0)
      points.push_back(cv::Point(col, row));
```